# Image before a span element (as inline-block) stop ::first-letter to apply

Tags: css

**My code:**

```css
span.badgeleft {
display: inline-block!important;
background-color: #F1F3F4;
padding: 10px 20px;
border-radius: 100px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
color: #1b2145;
font-family: Circularstd,sans-serif !important;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 16px;
}
span.badgeleft::first-letter {
text-transform: capitalize !important;
}
img.pinmapimg16 {
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: -4px;
width: 16px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Image before a span element as inline-block stop ::first-letter working</h3>
<span class="badgeleft"><img class="pinmapimg16" src="https://i.ibb.co/dgTs8Cf/map-pin-ico.png">i am with image before, first letter stop working</span>

<h3>No image before a span element as inline-block do not stop ::first-letter working</h3>
<span class="badgeleft">i do not have image before and first letter works fine</span>
```

Has anyone a a pure CSS solution to work ::first-letter for a span element that has an image before? (as you can see span is already inline-block).

Comment: Expected behavior. Do you have control of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first
> letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not
> preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

What to do about it? If you have control of the HTML you could put the img before the span (with any needed styling, perhaps in a span of its own) or you could consider putting the img as a background, suitably styled.

Comment: I accept this answer even I don't like it! :) If this is the rule of CSS Gods! I didn't know this part with "...but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables)."